# PHP Manage Out Of Memory Error

Tags: php

In my code I obtain this error:

```
php fatal error out of memory (allocated ) (tried to allocate bytes)
```

I try to insert the specific code into TRY CATCH block but the program already stop the execution.

How manage this error to ensure that the program continues the execution?

ie, take note of the error and continue running

Comment: It depends on many things Your code please

Comment: Please review [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question and post the code that produced that error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't catch that class of errors.

All you can do is Register a shutdown function to Log that Error.

https://insomanic.me.uk/php-trick-catching-fatal-errors-e-error-with-a-custom-error-handler-cea2262697a2#.oqtjicwor

Comment: so I can not continue with the program execution?

Comment: No. After all, PHP is out of it's memory Range. So you can't allocate any more memory.

Comment: You can increase the memory Limit though, so you don't run into that error so often

Comment: ok thanks, then there is a way to realize that I'm finishing the memory and thus interrupting the current operation (shortly before)

Comment: You could use http://php.net/manual/de/function.memory-get-usage.php to check the current allocation

Comment: thanks but in this mode I show the memory usage but I don't knon when i arrived at limit

Comment: Well you can compare the return Value against a Maximum Value.. you don't need to display it

Comment: Thanks, sorry how can obtain maximum value?

Comment: I think the option in my case is this : return_bytes(ini_get('post_max_size'))

Answer (score 0):

php.ini increase memory limit

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', 'XXM');
```

Comment: thanks I already insert in my code: ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); 
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); but obtain the same error

Comment: ini_set('memory_limit', '250M') this code is correct working try again.